# Can you use the speaker and microphone on a laptop for the raspberry pi 4b

Tags: pi-4, microphone, speakers

I was planning to build a voice assistant with my raspberry pi 4b but since google's AIY voice kit v1 doesn't ship to Australia, I was looking for other solutions. Can you use the speaker and the microphone on a laptop or a bluetooth speaker as an input and an output for the raspberry pi?